# web.sitemap generation

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I'm wondering if I may be going about this the wrong way and am looking for some guidance.

I've created a site map datasource on my website and I then created a site map for it to link to.  However, when I create the site map, it looks like I need to enter all the page details.  Is there some way of automating this (or at least getting it started)?  This is what it generated by default:

```
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="" title=""  description="">
    <siteMapNode url="" title=""  description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="" title=""  description="" />
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

For example, is there a way to get it to just list all the pages in the site at the same level or something?

Comment: I don't understand why this has been downvoted.  If the question isn't clear enought then please leave a comment at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this .NET forum question, no: http://forums.asp.net/t/1175101.aspx

However, they do suggest that there are several projects on CodeProject.com that may help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/useritems/DynamicSitemapASPNET2.asp
http://www.codeproject.com/useritems/ScionSiteMapProvider.asp
http://www.codeproject.com/aspnet/MutlipleSiteMap.asp
http://www.codeproject.com/useritems/Dynamic_Sitemap.asp

Good luck!